# scope for _token{0,1}, avoids stack too deep errors

Tags: solidity, uniswap, scope

this is from [UniswapV2Pair.sol](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol)

`token0` and `token1` are declared:

```
address public token0;
address public token1;
```

Then in `swap` function

```
 function swap( uint amount0Out,uint amount1Out,address to,bytes calldata data) external lock {
        require(
            amount0Out > 0 || amount1Out > 0,
            "UniswapV2: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT"
        );
        (uint112 _reserve0, uint112 _reserve1, ) = getReserves(); // gas savings
        require(
            amount0Out < _reserve0 && amount1Out < _reserve1,
            "UniswapV2: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY"
        );

        uint balance0;
        uint balance1;
        {
            // scope for _token{0,1}, avoids stack too deep errors
            address _token0 = token0;
            address _token1 = token1;
            require(to != _token0 && to != _token1, "UniswapV2: INVALID_TO");
            if (amount0Out > 0) _safeTransfer(_token0, to, amount0Out); // optimistically transfer tokens
            if (amount1Out > 0) _safeTransfer(_token1, to, amount1Out); // optimistically transfer tokens
            if (data.length > 0)
                IUniswapV2Callee(to).uniswapV2Call(
                    msg.sender,
                    amount0Out,
                    amount1Out,
                    data
                );
            balance0 = IERC20(_token0).balanceOf(address(this));
            balance1 = IERC20(_token1).balanceOf(address(this));
        }
       ......
    }
```

Inside function a new scope is opened and comment says: "// scope for _token{0,1}, avoids stack too deep errors". How does it avoid stack-too-deep errors and why Uniswap needs only for "_token{0,1}"? I searched and found out that

> Scoping a piece of code with { ... } has the same impact as placing
> that piece of code in a separate function.

Why did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every function provides a little stack for each function (Stack has a maximum depth of 1024 elements and supports the word size of 256 bits). So, that means that increase in local variables will ultimately fill up the stack fast.

Providing a separate scope for _token0, and _token1 helps in that issue. Since both these variables are just being used in these few lines, they can be put in a different scope, thus getting saved from the stack too deep errors.